# I would like to know the equivalent command to curl in Solaris

Tags: solaris, kvm-virtualization, curl

I would like to know equivalent command to `curl` in Solaris. As in Linux, the `curl` command is used to find the website activity.

Kindly let me know command to check website in Solaris.

Answer (score 4):

Curl is not a Linux command or a Solaris command, it's a Curl command - as in separate software from the operating system.

You need to install Curl on Solaris if you want to use it.

http://curl.haxx.se/

Answer (score 2):

`wget` comes bundled with Solaris 10. It's installed in `/usr/sfw/bin`. You can always also just install your own `curl`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

`wget`, `lynx`, `links`, and even netcat (`nc`) can all do similar things to `curl`.  One of them may already be installed on your Solaris system.  If not, you will need to install one of them or install curl.